# Laravel api passport Unauthorized 401

Tags: laravel, api

I have created a multi auth system for Laravel and I can log in and protecting the routes (with web and admin) defined in web.php is working fine. Now I also want to do the same for the api calls in api.php. For this purpose, I have installed Passport, changed my auth.php file to passport for api, attached the token in Kernel.php and in my axios request I attach xsrf and XMLHttpRequest. But when I execute my api call I get all the time 401 Unauthorized. I have taken a look in my headers and see a laravel_token and X-XSRF-TOKEN, so I am puzzled why it is not working.. Does anybody have any idea? Thanks!

Header looks like:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: undefined
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI....
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/availability/calendar
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 4SUDy8IJigeEBftGjTVgat7cqPSGnncA0zuSiEeI
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: dsfjkdsfsdj.....
```

In my api.php:

```
Route::post('/userStuff', 'MyController@userstuff')
->middleware('auth:api');
```

And my axios request:

```
axios.get("/api/userStuff").then(({data}) => {
            console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you please add some code example? It's very hard to help you without the code...

Comment: The relevant header is `Authorization` does your request include that?

Comment: No the header looks like: Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: undefined
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI....
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/availability/calendar
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: 4SUDy8IJigeEBftGjTVgat7cqPSGnncA0zuSiEeI
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: dsfjkdsfsdj.....

Comment: But that is the relevant header you need to include, that contains the API Auth. Maybe you should read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#protecting-routes "Passing The Access Token".